# Appending the extracted time stamp to a separate column in the data frame

Tags: r

```
dtime = strptime(Group_data[, 11], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
timestamp=strftime(dtime, format='%H:%M:%S')
```

I extracted the time stamp and would like to append these values as a column back to the original dataset. I am confused because I can not open up the extracted time values into a readable data frame like I can my other data. I thought I had created a variable "timestamp" so that I could then add that column of data back to the orginal dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, you should make:

```
Group_data$timestamp <- timestamp
```

To view the values as a column you can make on the console:

```
as.data.frame(timestamp)
```

Comment: What does Group_data$timestamp do?

Comment: This will create a column named `timestamp` on your original Group_data with the values of the vector `timestamp` you created in `timestamp=strftime(dtime, format='%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: replace `Group_data` with the name of your dataset then

Comment: I tried that and it did not create a column in the orginal dataframe. I was able to create a variable now of that column of data. timestamp=as.data.frame(timestamp). I can't get Group_data$timestamp to append that to the original dataset "Group_data".

Comment: figured it out!